# How to debug TensorFlow in Rstudio?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, rstudio

Any error using TensorFlow in R (https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow) leads to a useless error:

Error in py_call(attrib, args, keywords) : basic_string::_M_replace_aux

Is there a way to display the actual error from python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue fixed on TensorFlow for R recently that should add tracebacks in py error messages, please see:

https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/pull/42